# Accessing outside of public_html or httpdocs

Tags: php

In a way to secure my files from outside access, I am considering placing all the included files outside the public_html folder or the httpdocs folder.

However, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670263/accessing-php-code-outside-public-html-folder#comment20505810_14670263) is saying that nothing should be kept outside of the public folder that handles user input data.

What is the best and most ideal practice for this?  My thinking would be to have a .htaccess point route EVERYTHING to an index.php, and the index.php includes all the neccessary files such as database connections and whatever else, and also includes the .php file which would have the HTML and PHP inside it for the main body content of the page.

Can anyone tell me if there is anything wrong with that, and why?

Answer (score 2):

> However, this comment is saying that nothing should be kept outside of the public folder that handles user input data.

The comment uses the word **direct**. Includes are handling the data indirectly.

> My thinking would be to have a .htaccess

Configuration is better handled in the main configuration file if possible. `.htaccess` marginally is less efficient (and scatters configuration across your webroot).

> point route EVERYTHING to an index.php, and the index.php includes all the neccessary files such as database connections and whatever else, and also

[The front controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) is a perfectly reasonable approach.

> includes the .php file which would have the HTML and PHP inside it for the main body content of the page.

Simply including that can start to create a bit of a mess. I suggest investigating [the MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Use_in_web_applications).

Comment: I have investigated the MVC pattern, but each website I goto states a different way of approaching it.  I then get confused and i don't really know how to take it forward.  I would love to use it, but there are far to many conflicting opinions.  I guess my problem is I am looking for the perfect way, and there isn't one.  PHP seems to be very opinionated.

Comment: Pick a framework then do it that framework's way. Then you can start to form an opinion from experience.

Answer (score 1):

The comment you are referring to says that nothing that handles input or output *directly* should be outside the document root.

On the other hand, it's perfectly fine to place library code outside the root. If you use `index.php` as a single entry point to your application, pretty much the only things that should be web-accessible in addition to that script would be your assets (css, js, images, etc).